# findbyID is not returning individual item in db, 404 not found error , mongodb, mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Cycle Schema

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const cycleSchema= new Schema({
     
     startDate:{type:Date,required:true},
     endDate:{type:Date,required:true},
     users:[
       {
        firstName:String,
        lastName:String,
        goals:[{
            mainGoal:String,
            progress:{
                type:Number,
                default:0
            },
            subTasks: [{
                task:String,
                done:Boolean
            }]
        }]
       }
     ]    
},{
    timestamps:true
})

const Cycle= mongoose.model('Cycle', cycleSchema)

module.exports = Cycle
```

And we import the above model to routes file as below

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const Cycle = require('../models/cycle.model')


router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{
    console.log("getting cycles ..")
    Cycle.find()
    .then(cycle=>res.json(cycle))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json("Error "+ err))
})


router.route('/add').post((req,res)=>{
 
const startDate= Date.parse ( req.body.startDate) 
const endDate=  Date.parse ( req.body.endDate) 
 

const users=req.body.users


const newCycle=new Cycle({
    startDate,endDate,users
})


router.route('/:id').get((req,res)=>{
    
    Cycle.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(cycle=>res.json(cycle))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
}) 

module.exports = router
```

And this is imported in server.js

```js
const cyclesRouter=require('./routes/cycles')


app.use('/cycles', cyclesRouter)
```

then we run the server and try the Get cycles request in postman we get something like this

[image]

But when we try to get that specific cycle by using the id parameter as below , we get the 404 error as below
[image]

The mongodb CLI has the following structure
[image]
Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: I think `req.params._id` should be `req.params.id`

Comment: thanks req.params.id doesnt work either,

Comment: did you add `module.exports = router;` in your `cycleRouter.js` .

Comment: Yes stacks, it is there in the router cycle router file

Comment: your code should works fine. I tried it in my local too. try change the method from get to get for the sake of if postman could really reach the url. then change your method in postman too

Comment: the console.logs we put inside the .`get((req,res))=> { console.log("test")}` doesn't log anything either, so im not sure how to test if postman can reach the url, '/' returns all cycles , but /:id doesnt return anything just 404 error

Comment: try to change get to post and see if postman really reach your api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249116/discussion-between-naveen-dinushka-and-stacks-queue).

Comment: for the record, the same code works, i have put in that as the answer, posting it here helped

Answer (score 1):

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


Cycle.findById(new ObjectId(req.params._id))
    .then(cycle=>res.json(cycle))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
```

Comment: try this one now

Comment: sorry that, didnt work either

Comment: Cycle.findById({_id:req.params.id})

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the error is in the route and not the query based on the response from Postman.

Try removing the additional '.route()' which is not necessary unless you are chaining HTTP methods.

```
router.get('/:id', (req,res)=>{
    
    Cycle.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(cycle=>res.json(cycle))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})
```

Or with some additional error checking...

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {

  Cycle.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(cycle => {
      if (!cycle) {
        return next(console.log(`Cycle with id ${req.params.id} not found`))
      } else {
        return res.json(cycle)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both of the snippets, it doesn't console.log anything at all, just gives the 404 error

Comment: Could be something to do with the order of route matching. Change the path to router.get(‘/details/:id’) or something to make is more distinct.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the question would be , Change the code for get id request to post, delete and try to hit it through postman, Try multiple times and give it 1hr. Put the same code in as before

```js
router.route('/:id').get((req,res)=>{
    
    Cycle.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(cycle=>res.json(cycle))
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('Error:' + err) )
})
```

Delete all items in the database and create new items/ add items (do this from the front-end ), then try to access the api url for individual cycle from frontend, then check Postman again, one of these attempts should work, and it worked for me.

[image]